# Corda: Making HTTP request within a responder flow?

Tags: corda

Is it okay to make HTTP requests to a counter party's external service from within a responder flow?

My use case is a Party invokes a "request-token" flow with an exchange node. That exchange node makes a HTTP request (on the responder flow) to move cash from that parties account to an exchange account in the external payment system. The event of the funds actually hitting the count and hence the issuance of the tokens would happen with another flow.

If it is not okay, what may be an alternative design to achieve the task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not always a good idea to make HTTP request that way.

Unless you think very carefully about what happens when the previous checkpoint is replayed.so dedupe and idempotence are key considerations.plus what happens if target is down? plus this may exhaust the thread pool upon which the fibers operate.

Flows are run on fibers. CordaServices can spawn their own threads
threads can block on I/O, fibers can only do so for short periods and we make no guarantees about freeing resources, or ordering unless it is the DB. Also threads can register observables

The real challenge is restart-ability and for that they need to test the hell out of their code with a random kills.

You need to be aware that steps can be replayed in the event of a crash. this is true of any server-side work based system that restarts work.

Effectively, you should:

- Step 1) execute an on-ledger Corda transaction to move one or more
  assets into a locked state (analogous to XA 'prepare'). When
  successfully notarised,
- Step 2) execute the off-ledger transaction
  with an idempotent call that succeeds or fails.  When we know if it
  succeeded or failed, move to
- Step 3) execute a second Corda
  transaction that either reverts the status of the asset or moves it
  to its intended final state